# Dimension 4500 upgrade RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows

Dad's got a Dimension 4500 which maxes out with 1 GB RAM. We want to upgrade W XP to W 7 - would adding an external hard drive work??

Comment: "Work" in what way?  As a drive? Probably.  As a replacement for RAM? No.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 requirements are listed at: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements

Apparently having only 1GB of RAM is supported.

RAM has absolutely nothing to do with your hard drive.  Those are two different components of the system.  To clarify a bit.  Available Hard Drive space is going to determine whether you have room to install the update.  Amount of RAM determines whether you have enough memory to actually run it.  Those are two very different things.

However, the Dimension 4500 shipped with a NVIDIA GeForce4 Ti 4200 video chip.  This video chip does not support DirectX 9.. which is a requirement of Windows 7.  **Unless you've upgraded the video to one that is DirectX 9 compatible, Win 7 will not install on that system.**

If your dad is intent on upgrading, then it's probably a far cheaper path to simply purchase a new computer.

Comment: +1 For getting a new computer. I wouldn't even want to run XP with only 1GB of RAM.

Comment: @suz My Dad just bought a used HP Core2Duo desktop machine with 4GB of RAM, 1TB HDD, Windows 7 and a no-name 21" LCD monitor for <$400CND.  I agree with Chris, it's time to upgrade the whole computer. ;)

Comment: @David: I agree.  Sure, win7 can run with only 1GB of RAM.. but only for certain definitions of "run". -- mainly the ones that mean "you have time to get your coffee, donuts and can probably take your car down to the oil change place before it's ready for you to click on something."